# sum looks ugly in \frac

Tags: math-mode

I want to use sum in a fraction, but it doesn't like it should.
Here's my code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \rho=\sum_{I=1}^{N}y_I
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \rho=\frac{\sum_{I=1}^{N}y_I}{\sum_{I=1}^{N}x_I}
\end{equation}
```

As a reference I've added two images below. one with sum, as it should look, and the other one as a fraction.

[image]

I want the sum in `\frac{}{}` to like it does in a normal equation, that is, the sum range at top and bottom.

I have no idea how to implement that. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: One option is to use `\limits`: `\rho=\frac{\sum\limits_{I=1}^{N}y_I}{\sum\limits_{I=1}^{N}x_I}`.

Comment: Keep it like it is. TeX does this for a reason. Having two full-size summations in enumerator and denominator looks *terrible*.